# Intersection Bound

Tags: probability

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5K5F.jpg)Let $A_1, A_2, \ldots$   be events

Show that $$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \right) \geq \sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i) -(n-1)$$

where $P$ is the probability.

Comment: how do you denote the sums of probability of events

Comment: I tried to guess your question. Please check whether that is what you are asking. It would be great to tell us what you have tried and where do you get stucked. It's nice to pick up Mathjax as that would make communication smoother.

Comment: Apologies for not making it informative, I have added a picture and it is easy to see it. I am starting with De morgans Law and then using Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion. I cant get to the final result

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference mathjax resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By union bound,
$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i^c \right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i^c) $$
By De Morgan's Law,
$$P\left(\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \right)^c\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n[1-P(A_i)] $$

$$1-P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \right) \leq n-\sum_{i=1}^n[P(A_i)] $$

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much!! Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

See whether the mathematics of the following make sense to you:

> There are $30$ people in a room. Twenty of them play an instrument. Fifteen of them play football. Therefore at least five of them do both.

If it makes sense, then you understand the basic mechanisms of why what you have is true. If not, no explanation that I am capable of writing on a web page is going to help you. You need to read the above sentence and explore it on your own. Drawing might also help.